# Matrix multiplication over range in $O(n)$

Tags: time-complexity, data-structures, arrays, matrices

Let $Q$ denote the number of queries.

I have a $25 \times 25$ matrix in each cell of an array of size $n$. Let us denote this array by $A$. It's a special matrix, more specifically, all elements are $0$ are $1$ and only on cells adjacent to the main diagonal and on the main diagonal itself, allowing faster multiplication.

I have $Q$ queries, each represented by 2 values, $l$ and $r$. Each query needs to be answered by the multiplication of all matrices between the indexes $l$ and $r$. More specifically $\Pi_{i=l}^{r} A_i$. Let $l_i$ denote the value of $l$ for the $i$th query and similarly for $r$. It is given that $l_{i-1}\le l_i$ and $r_{i-1}\le r_i$for all valid $i$.

I can use a segment tree and answer queries, However that adds an unwanted $\log{n}$ factor. I want to know if there is some faster algorithm, that will allow me to answer all queries in $O(Q+n)$ multiplications. Unfortunately, The matrices are not necessarily invertible.

I believe it's some application of 2 pointers, But I'm not able to figure out how exactly it would work.

Comment: [Alon and Schieber](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.79.1554&rep=rep1&type=pdf) showed that on an arbitrary semigroup, if you are only allowed linear preprocessing, then a single query takes $\Omega(\alpha(n))$ time. However, in your case you can assume that you have many queries, so perhaps this can be beaten somehow. Otherwise, you need to use some particular properties of your semigroup.

Comment: [Chazelle and Rosenberg](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/S0218195991000049) extended that result to the offline setting. The time per query is $\alpha(Q,n)$, and in particular isn't constant. So you need to use some particular properties of your semigroup.

Comment: Please try and adjust the title of this question.

Comment: What are your space constraints and do you have any constraints on preprocessing time you’ll allow? Because if neither of these two things were concerns, you could just precompute all products for all pairs $(l,r)$ and store them in $O(n^2)$ space in a table, making each query possible in constant time.

Comment: @spektr At best I can have $O(n)$ preprocessing time.

Comment: What does "all elements are 0 are 1 and only on cells adjacent to the main diagonal and on the main diagonal itself" mean?  I think there is something wrong with the wording.  Please [edit].

Comment: What's the context where you encountered this task?  What's the motivation?

Comment: @D.W. I was trying to become a problem setter. My question was to find paths in a grid with walls, Where you can go LU, LD and L in one turn. I initially thought of making it a segment tree of matrices, But that was too obvious. Then I though of using query square root decomposition. Which was less obvious, especially to notice the $O(n^2)$ matrix multiplication. But then TL would have been to large, Which is a dead giveaway for square root decomposition. Then I thought of only moving the pointers forward. Then I realised I didn't know how that would work, and it looks like a simpler query.